Incorrect Visualization on Grafana
The data displayed by Grafana is accurate, but the consumer lag peak appears as an outlier. Ideally, this data should be visible within the normal time frame, but it only shows up when we reduce the time frame. I have verified the data on Prometheus, and it confirms this observation.
Grafana Version:9.5.2
Prometheus Version:2.32.1
PromQL Query
kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{instance="$instance",topic=~"$topic", consumergroup=~"$consumergroup"}

Kafka Exporter:https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter
Please find the screenshots for the same
Fig: Showing the Consumer Lag of last 2 days

Fig: Showing the Consumer Lag  of last 12 hours

Fig: Showing the Consumer Lag  of that particular duration (~11:00 am (IMT)).

Conclusion:
Ideally, when viewing data from the last 2 or 7 days, we should be able to see all the peaks. However, this is not currently happening. We can only see the peaks (outliers) when we zoom in or decrease the time frame.
Please help  me in finding the solution for the same.

Why are talking about Grafana being incorrect, but sharing graphs from Prometheus' web console? Do you understand that those are two different systems, and Grafana is not involved in process of getting graphs in your screenshots?

Problem in your case is that Prometheus (and Grafana too) visualizes data with some resolution; after all there only so much pixels to do that. To do this Prometheus (and Grafana) uses parameter Step passed with the query (can be editied on panels in your screenshots in field Res. (s)).

But it is still limited, and you cannot set it to one second and query a month (or probably even a day): you'll get an error. To see all data you'd need to aggregate your data using <aggr>_over_time functions. In this exact case you're probably interested in sum_over_time.
